# Can't seem to run my crontab file on my chromeos chroot

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-18.04, crouton

I have written a python script that will change my desktop wallpaper on my Lxde crouton shell, that seems to run just fine:

```
import os
from time import localtime
from pathlib import Path

wp = Path("/home/lucasmccallums/Desktop/projects/wallpaper_transitions")


hour = localtime().tm_hour

if (hour < 6) or (hour >= 21):
    os.system("pcmanfm --set-wallpaper=" + str(wp / "night.png"))

elif (hour >= 14):
    os.system("pcmanfm --set-wallpaper=" + str(wp / "afternoon.png"))

else:
    os.system("pcmanfm --set-wallpaper=" + str(wp / "morning.png"))
```

However when I try to run it through crontab as
`*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/lucasmccallums/Desktop/projects/wallpaper_transitions/desktopdemo.py`
It seemingly installs fine
 `crontab: installing new crontab` 
However it still doesn't seem to work. I try to use the command
`/etc/init.d/cron start`
 But am faced with
`cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied`

I shall keep updating as I try to figure this out but
any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 0):

On Crontab

```
0 6,14,21 * * */usr/bin/somedirectory/py.....
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.